# Trying to setClob() In JDBC to insert a string to Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to insert data as clob in oracle database and the code i am using for inserting is as below:

```
Connection connection = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try
    {
        System.out.println("datra i retrive is : " + status + "  " + operationType + "   " + errorLog + "    " + clipBoardId);
        int i = 0;
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_CODELIST_BATCH_UPDATE);
        ps.setString(++i, status);
        
        /*ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(errorLog.getBytes());
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);*/
        
        Clob clob = (java.sql.Clob)oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(
                  connection, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
        clob.setString(1, errorLog);
        
        ps.setClob(++i, clob);
        ps.setString(++i, operationType);
        ps.setString(++i, clipBoardId);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        close(ps);
        close(connection);
    }
```

and if i am trying to insert above code at the `setClob()` method its giving exception as below:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy43 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
>
> at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:676)
>
> at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:640)

And if I'm trying to create the `CLOB` as below

```
Clob clob = connection.createClob()
```

and setting the string value as

```
clob.setString(1, "test code");
```

and it is stuck at `createClob();`

Comment: In what environment do you run your code, e.g. in Tomcat? How do you create or retrieve the database connection?

Comment: What do you mean by "stucking at createClob()"? Does it crash? Doesn't it compile? Or does the code hang, i.e. not continue to execute?

Comment: stucking means after createClob() it's directly going to finally block and the envirnment is tomcat and before doing the operation i am doing an insert and then i am trying to update data and one of the data column is clob

Comment: CLOB.createTemporary has a BUG if you are not using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a method that only work with `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection` instances. And Tomcat only passes you a proxy connection that actively prevent from being unwrapped to access the real Oracle connection. Furthmore, the entire `oracle.sql.CLOB` class is deprected now.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got the solution and its working for me

Instead of creating

```
Clob clob = connection.createClob();
clob.setClob(<parameter>, clob object);
```

what i did is used the method

```
ps.setCharacterStream(<parameter>, inputStreamReader, inputStream.available());
```

And its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the best if you have a large amount of data to store into the `CLOB`. Otherwise you can just use `ps.setString` just as if the column was a `VARCHAR` instead of a `CLOB`.